# XSLT check values in for each and set value of element

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am not expert in XSLT. I have requirement to check all "code" values, set statuscode as per below rules.

1. If all code values are 200, then set statuscode to 200 and reasonphrase to success
2. If all code values are either 200 or 204, then set status code to 200 and reasonphrase is concatnatiopn of all reason which have code other than 200.
3. If atleast one code contains value other than 200 and 204, then set statuscode to 503 and reasonphrase is concatnatiopn of all reason which have code other than 200.

I have tried couple of ways which are to store all code values in one variable and execeute contains function with above conditions as well as create code variables and store values and then check string length. But i did not get any success.

I am looking for some more generic way if possible as this requirement is  part of complex xslt and below is just an example of requirement. 
Once i get logic for below code, i should be able to fit logic in complex xslt.

I also tried to search in answers but could not get any solution which fits this requirement.

I am looking for solution in xslt 1.0 as other part of xslt is written in xslt 1.0

Input -

```
            <root>
                <Node1>
                        <code>200</code>
                        <reason>Success</reason>
                </Node1>
                <Node1>
                        <code>200</code>
                        <reason>Success</reason>
                </Node1>
                <Node1>
                        <code>204</code>
                        <reason>Business Error</reason>
                </Node1>
                <Node1>
                        <code>500</code>
                        <reason>Tech Error</reason>
                </Node1>
                <Node1>
                        <code>200</code>
                        <reason>Success</reason>
                </Node1>
            </root>
```

Output-

```
            <root>
            <output>
                <statuscode></statuscode>
                <reasonphrase></reasonphrase>
            </output>
            </root>
```

Thank you.

Comment: "I am looking for solution in xslt 1.0 as other part of xslt is written in xslt 1.0" - that's not actually a very good reason. It's a bit like sticking with JDK 1.4 because other parts of your app use JDK 1.4. Except that XSLT 1.0 has been obsolete for a lot longer than JDK 1.4 has.

Comment: Yes i do agree. But XSLT is going to be integrated in TIBCO code. As compare to whole TIBCO code, it is just 10%. So, project team is ok with xslt 1.0. 
But thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your starting point:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <output>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="not(Node1[code!=200])">
                    <!-- all code values are 200 -->
                    <statuscode>200</statuscode>
                    <reasonphrase>success</reasonphrase>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="not(Node1[code!=200 and code!=204])">
                    <!-- all code values are either 200 or 204 -->
                    <statuscode>200</statuscode>
                    <reasonphrase>
                        <xsl:for-each select="Node1[code!=200]">
                            <xsl:value-of select="code"/>
                            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>  
                    </reasonphrase>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <statuscode>503</statuscode>
                    <reasonphrase>
                        <xsl:for-each select="Node1[code!=200]">
                            <xsl:value-of select="code"/>
                            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>  
                    </reasonphrase>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </output>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that this could be streamlined to eliminate repeating code - but the point here is to show how to test for the given conditions.